# Keep Jboss instance alive after closing the terminal

Tags: java, windows, jboss

I'm running a Jboss Instance on Windows server 2012, starting the server with the following command

```
C:\>standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0
```

Server is up and no issues but once I close the Command Window, the server stops. Is there any way to keep the process alive even after the close of the command window?

Answer (score 0):

You could start Jboss as a Windows Service: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/run-jboss-as-service-howto